# TS: question about exporting class vs type

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I created an NPM package that exports a class
**mypackage/user/user.dto.ts**

```js
import { IsString } from 'class-validator'

export class UserDTO {
  @IsString()
  name: string
}
```

and then when importing it into my Nestjs app:
**user.controller.ts**

```js
import { UserDTO } from 'mypackage/user/user.dto' // Error: Cannot find module 'mypackage/user/user.dto'

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  async login(@Body() dto: UserDTO): Promise<any> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

However, this error is resolved when I export it as a type:

```js
import { IsString } from 'class-validator'

class User {
  @IsString()
  name: string
}

export type UserDTO = User
```

Now when importing it is found and works as expected. Is there some type of documentation or article related to this that I can learn more to understand why this is happening

Comment: `user.dto.ts` using `.` in filenames is likely not a great idea,.  Does it work OK if you used something like -> `user-dto.ts` ?

Comment: nestjs documentation uses `.` notation for this so i'm keeping with their naming convention